# Reference request: linearly independent cycles in a manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

The following seems to be well known to experts, but I would be happy if there is a paper or textbook that I can cite.

Note: all of the manifolds are assumed to be without boundary.

Suppose that $C$ is an open manifold, and that it contains two sets of submanifolds:

$Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_n$ are $j$-dimensional compact submanifolds, and
$Z^*_1, Z^*_2, \dots, Z^*_n$ are $j$-codimensional closed submanifolds.

Suppose further that
$$Z_i \cap Z^*_j = \emptyset$$
whenever $i \neq j$,
and that $Z_i$ intersects $Z^*_i$ transversely in a single point for every $i$.

Then $\dim H_j (X, \mathbb{Z}/2) \ge n$.

(Bonus question: Moreover, if the submanifolds are all orientable, then the same holds with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients.)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is citeable: it's just Poicare duality. $Z_1$ through $Z_n$ represent certain classes in $H_j$, whereas $Z_1^*$ through $Z_n^*$, classes in the dual space $H_{N-j}^c=H^j$; the condition asserts that they are linearly independent as (sub-)bases dual to each other. So, the right citation is either "obvious" or "Poincare duality".

Comment: Is there a reason that the hypothesis on $Z_i$ just says "compact" while the hypothesis on $Z_i^*$ says "closed"?  Are you allowing the manifolds $Z_i$ to have boundary?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason that the hypothesis on $Z_i$ is compact and the hypothesis on $Z^*_i$ is merely closed. The short answer is that in the special case I am interested in, this is what we have, but I also think that this is a useful and fairly general formulation which is true. Also: we do know that none of the manifolds have boundary.

Comment: @DanRamras The compact ones represent classes in $H_*$, whereas the closed ones, in the homology with closed supports, which are isomorphic to $H^*$ (Poincare duality). This distinction is essential if the ambient manifold is not compact.

Comment: I misread the question I guess.  I read "closed submanifold" to mean "a submanifold that is a closed manifold" whereas you meant "a submanifold that is a closed subspace."

Comment: Is this a topology question or a linear algebra question? There are two ingredients to reduce to linear algebra: that the manifolds give homology and cohomology classes (so that you have a maps from $k^n$ to $H_j$ and $H^j$); and that transverse intersection is cap product. Now you have a linear algebra question about the *rank* of a bilinear form, specifically that a bilinear form with invertible determinant has full rank. So it detects every element of $k^n$, yet the form factors through $H_j$, so there was no kernel.